# How can I test Firebase Dynamic Links if my app is not in the App Store?

Tags: firebase, app-store, firebase-dynamic-links

I'd like to be able to open the app and print the parameters when I click on the dynamic link (even though it's not published).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you seen this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38736094/4625829) before? Maybe implement the same and just include some logs where you need them?

Answer (score 103):

Yes! In fact, I go through this exact process in the getting started videoS [(part 1)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLBjAg6HvG0), [(part 2)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iSC5ed6OowA), which I recommend you check out if you haven't yet.

But, generally speaking, you can test the "Open my app if I have it installed" flow simply by clicking on a dynamic link. If your app is installed on the device, it should open up just fine; even if it's not a published app.

If you want to test the non-installed flow, this is pretty easy, too.

- First, give your Firebase project an app store ID in your project settings. It can be any **valid** App store ID -- it doesn't have to be for your app.
- Then generate a new dynamic link.
- This time, when you click on this new link, it should take you to the app store for the ID you listed above. You don't need to actually install this app -- just making it to the app store listing is good enough.
- Now, go ahead and reinstall and run your app. If everything is working properly, it should retrieve and display the dynamic link data for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot- it worked as expected. 
Minor addition: for quick testing, you dont even need App store Id- just click on dynamic link, it would go to play store and show "Item not found". 
Next simply install your app- it will automatically receive the link from intent and behave as though link was pressed..

Comment: This is a nice way to test the non-installed flow. I found out that when the app is installed the method `application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler` is called but when the app is NOT installed the method `app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options` is called. @Todd Kerpelman is that correct?

Comment: Perfect answer!

Comment: @Tom Spee's comment also helped here.. +1

Comment: @Todd, When we click on dynamic link
Scenario 1 : When app installed :: We get URL properly.
Scenario 2 : when the app is NOT INSATLLED, we get the URL as NULL. How to get this in this situation?  code reference screenshot https://prntscr.com/vfz4jj

Comment: Make sure to add `FirebaseApp.configure()` inside`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` or app will open, but the dynamic links will not be handled.

Comment: Is this solution also working for Android and the Play store?

Comment: any idea how can we test the no-installed flow for android?

Comment: @D0m3 did you find any way to test the same on android?

Comment: I tried this and I just get "CapacitorFirebaseDynamicLinks.handleLink() - Dynamic link has no url"

Comment: Ah! It only works if the preview page is enabled.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/1244#issuecomment-502469160

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issues, and after spending many hours trying to found a solution, and following the instruction to debug explained by Todd Kerpelman [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41050772/5243421), I could identify that the firebase has not sent a universal link on the first app launch and has sent the scheme URL with the following structure:

```
[bundle_id]://google/link/?deep_link_id=[firebase_universal_link]
```

After identifying that, I found the `dynamicLinkFromCustomSchemeURL` method inside of the Firesabe SDK and I could solve my problem on the first app launch by dynamic links.

```
/**
 * @method dynamicLinkFromCustomSchemeURL:
 * @abstract Get a Dynamic Link from a custom scheme URL. This method parses URLs with a custom
 *     scheme, for instance, "comgoogleapp://google/link?deep_link_id=abc123". It is suggested to
 *     call it inside your |UIApplicationDelegate|'s
 *     |application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation| and |application:openURL:options:|
 *     methods.
 * @param url Custom scheme URL.
 * @return Dynamic Link object if the URL is valid and has link parameter, otherwise nil.
 */
- (nullable FIRDynamicLink *)dynamicLinkFromCustomSchemeURL:(NSURL *)url
    NS_SWIFT_NAME(dynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL:));

/**
 * @method dynamicLinkFromUniversalLinkURL:completion:
 * @abstract Get a Dynamic Link from a universal link URL. This method parses the universal link
 *     URLs, for instance,
 *     "https://example.page.link?link=https://www.google.com&ibi=com.google.app&ius=comgoogleapp".
 *     It is suggested to call it inside your |UIApplicationDelegate|'s
 *     |application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:| method.
 * @param URL Custom scheme URL.
 * @param completion A block that handles the outcome of attempting to get a Dynamic Link from a
 * universal link URL.
 */
- (void)dynamicLinkFromUniversalLinkURL:(NSURL *)url
                             completion:(FIRDynamicLinkUniversalLinkHandler)completion
    NS_SWIFT_NAME(dynamicLink(fromUniversalLink:completion:));

/**
 * @method dynamicLinkFromUniversalLinkURL:
 * @abstract Get a Dynamic Link from a universal link URL. This method parses universal link
 *     URLs, for instance,
 *     "https://example.page.link?link=https://www.google.com&ibi=com.google.app&ius=comgoogleapp".
 *     It is suggested to call it inside your |UIApplicationDelegate|'s
 *     |application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:| method.
 * @param url Custom scheme URL.
 * @return Dynamic Link object if the URL is valid and has link parameter, otherwise nil.
 */
```

Comment: hi, I am facing the same issue...
can you elaborate more about dynamicLinkFromCustomSchemeURL or  send me the code