# Firebase dynamic links data doesn't survive the app installation process in Expo app

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm using Firebase dynamic links for referrals in an Expo app (managed workflow), but the link data isn't surviving the app installation process. The links worked fine when testing with a standalone app: when the user didn't have the app, they got directed to the App Store/Play Store* and when they did have the app, the link was handled using Expo's `Linking.getInitialUrl()`.

I've actually gone ahead and published a native binary that displays a modal with the link data upon signing up to the app** (again, using `Linking.getInitialUrl()`). The modal only displays the app's custom url scheme `myapp://`. This same test displayed the link as expected when testing with a standalone app.

Note that the links work as expected if the app is already installed.

*[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39605657/how-can-i-test-firebase-dynamic-links-if-my-app-is-not-in-the-app-store) seems to suggest that this is enough to ensure the data will pass

**Fortunately we are very early stage with no users lol

Comment: Hey thanks for raising the issue - I actully encountered the exact same problem and was wondering if you could share any updates on whether or how you have solved this? Thanks