# onContinueUserActivity referral links

Tags: swiftui, app-store

How does one test app referral links?
I want to know how to get my referral link if the user downloads the app from App Store

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/app-name/id1111111?referralURL=mydomain.com?key=value

```swift
RootView()
   .onContinueUserActivity(NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb, perform: { userActivity in
       userActivity.referrerURL
   })
```

Is the `userActivity.referrerURL` going to be `mydomain.com?key=value`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the non-installed flow, this is pretty easy, too.

First, give your Firebase project an app store ID in your project settings. It can be any valid App store ID -- it doesn't have to be for your app.
Then generate a new dynamic link.
This time, when you click on this new link, it should take you to the app store for the ID you listed above. You don't need to actually install this app -- just making it to the app store listing is good enough.
Now, go ahead and reinstall and run your app. If everything is working properly, it should retrieve and display the dynamic link data for you.

from [How can I test Firebase Dynamic Links if my app is not in the App Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39605657/how-can-i-test-firebase-dynamic-links-if-my-app-is-not-in-the-app-store)