# How to test Firebase Dynamic Link with TestFlight (Unpublished ios app)

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store, testflight, firebase-dynamic-links

Developing a small app in react native for both android and ios, where I need to open my app by clicking on a **firebase dynamic link**.

This app is not published yet in AppStore, right now it is in TestFlight environment. I never have any experience in ios so don't know how to check the dynamic link with TestFlight.

In the Android Beta Environment, it is working very well. I am able to redirect in play store if the app is not already installed. If installed then the app opens itself.

The same scenario I want to test in ios before publishing to AppStore. Currently, it is in TestFlight Environment and unable to redirect if the app is not installed.

**I have gone through some post but no luck yet, posts are:**

[How can I test Firebase Dynamic Links if my app is not in the App Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39605657/how-can-i-test-firebase-dynamic-links-if-my-app-is-not-in-the-app-store)

[Test Firebase Dynamic Links for Unpublished App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38707945/test-firebase-dynamic-links-for-unpublished-app/38736094#38736094)

Can anyone please suggest how I can test with TestFlight or is there any other possible way to check my dynamic link working fine or not?

Comment: Interested as well by the solution

Answer (score 7):

Firebase Dynamic Links will function when App is in TestFlight. Keep in mind:

1) User who tap on the link must have access to your iOS Beta App in TestFlight. I believe, to make this happens you need to invite user to TestFlight first.

2) You can specify "ifl"/"afl" parameter during dynamic link creation. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually . If this parameter is specified, the user will be navigated to your custom link, not AppleStore/PlayStore.

yes we can test app with testflight by testflight urischeme `itms-beta://`

```
itms-beta://
```

**Note:** i did not test but i think this will work. let me know the result of it. may be i can help you futher

Comment: Hi, I wasn't clear whether using the testflight urischem was intended to be different from using the custom link via ifl/afi?  because I believe the testflight link is just https....